# Count the total number of trees from DSM drone data

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, global-mapper

We have a DSM, DTM and ortho data processed from a drone survey with a resolution of 5cm.

Are there any methods to "automatically calculate" the total number of estimated trees inside a dense vegetation forest area using Global mapper, QGIS, or GRASS software and mark it as a vector point?

Answer (score 2):

There's a software; SAGA GIS. It might be useful for this case using this tutorial - http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2012/02/simple-method-to-count-trees-using-saga.html